# Use TableRow In a Sentence/Paragraph without an actual table?

Tags: ms-word, docusignapi, tablerow

I'm using DocuSign to generate word documents and require to retrieve data via their TableRow xPath tag (as detailed in https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/SpringCM-Document-Generation). To do so I need to place the TableRow tag inside an actual table
"The TableRow tag must be at the beginning of the first cell in the impacted row of the table (template row)."

However I would prefer to use it in the middle of a paragraph/sentence instead of within a table.  I've tried today to format a table within a sentence and have found it very difficult to do so without it breaking out into a new row or requiring a new row in the word doc.  I wondered if there are any known tips for this requirement?  How to use a table in a sentence/paragraoh while retaining it with the look of the enclosing sentence?

Thanks in advance for any tips on this.

Comment: You can fairly easily extract the contents of a cell without a table. To extract a row will mean extracting the contents of each cell and replicating them. This is not a code writing service. Show us your code and someone here may be able to help.  Unless you modify your question, I would expect it to be closed in fairly short order. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @CharlesKenyon Thanks for your help. Noted of course that it's not a code writing service. As it's just a few tags I was not sure what to include.  I have resolved my issue using "Repeat" instead as follows                                          <# <Repeat Select="/Opportunity//MyRelatedList__r" /> #>
 Process as required
<# <EndRepeat/> #>.       Thankfully it allows the rendering without a table.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Using Repeat tags instead has met my requirements.

```
<# <Repeat Select="/Opportunity//MyRelatedList__r" /> #> 
   Process as required 
<# <EndRepeat/> #>
```

Comment: Is this for Microsoft word? This syntax gave me an error when generating: The template and data provided for document generation resulted in an invalid document. Reference Id: acb89c